# Is every point of every open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point of $E$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

This is exercise #8 in chapter 2 of Rudin's PMA.

> Is every point of every open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point of $E?$.

This statement is true, for if there exists a point $p\in E$ such that $p$ is not a limit point of $E$, then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N\cap E=\{p\}$. This is a contradiction since $\{p\}$ is closed and $N\cap E$ is open.

My proof suggests that this statement would still be valid if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is replaced by any non-discrete metric space, but at the same time, I know that would not be true because if so the author would not have chosen to use $\mathbb{R}^2$ here. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: What about $E=\Bbb N$?

Comment: Discrete metric space

Comment: @AndrewZhang Can $\mathbb{R}^2$ be replaced by any non-discrete metric space?

Comment: You have to replace "nondiscrete" by "containing no isolated points." Then the claim holds, otherwise, it does not.

Comment: @kmiyazaki if you look at your proof, you end up with trivial clopen subsets. So a sufficient condition is any connected space.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I see. So, a singleton set $\{p\}$ is closed in any metric space $X$. If we further assume $X$ is connected, then $\{p\}$ is not open and the line $N\cap E=\{p\}$ in my proof will be a contradiction if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is replaced by any connected space?